# Attempts to test against a HiveContext when dependencies are provided throws java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly, spark-hive

When running unit tests that create a spark context I get an  `java.lang.SecurityException`. I understand what the cause is but not sure how to track down how to solve it. This being that multiple dependencies sharing the same package `javax.servlet` having different signer information.

```
// Dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.6.2" % Provided
)

// Test dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % Test,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % Test,
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-minicluster" % "2.5.0" % Test
)
```

I've created a [sample project to demonstrate this](https://github.com/brettryan/spark-unit-testing-example).

There are many examples of this same problem which suggest exclusion rules for `org.mortonbay.jetty` and `javax.servlet`, though none seem to work for me.

when I use `spark-submit` on the built `sbt assembly` jar it works file, I just can't write tests for it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured out the issue. It turns out that the dependency tree that's causing the problem is actually in my test dependencies, not the runtime dependencies.

Updating to the following has resolved the issue.

```
// Test dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % Test,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % Test,
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-minicluster" % "2.5.0" % Test
).map(
  _.excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet"))
)
```

I've updated the sample on github.